# Convert JSON values into their appropriate data types

Tags: java, json

I have some Json data and I need to return each value as a string or number or which data type it returns..
But I am facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Validation
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

```
  public class Validation {
        public void readJSON() throws Exception {
                File file = new File("myJSONFile.txt");
                String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8");

                // Convert JSON string to JSONObject
                JSONObject tomJsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
                System.out.println(tomJsonObject);
                System.out.println(tomJsonObject.getString("age"));
                validateByType(tomJsonObject, "age", null);
            }

            public void validateByType(JSONObject jsonString, String pathString, String typeString)
                    throws JSONException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
                String jsonField = jsonString.getString(pathString);
                // pathString = "age";
                // typeString ="number";

                Class<?> c = Class.forName("Validation");
                Field f = c.getField(jsonField);
                System.out.format("Type: %s%n", f.getType());
                System.out.format("GenericType: %s%n", f.getGenericType());

            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Test");
                Validation v = new Validation();
                try {
                    v.readJSON();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: It would help to have the full stack trace with line numbers. At a first glance, the exception seems to be generated by `Class.forName("Validation");`. `Validation` must be in the default package

Comment: In this Package ------- package com.sample.validation; import java.io.File; import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; import org.json.JSONException; import org.json.JSONObject; import java.lang.reflect.Field;

Answer (score 0):

The Class.forName() method takes the fully qualified name of the class as a parameter while you are passing the simple name of the class resulting in a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: So What should I pass In that Method??

Comment: @sandi In what package is your Validation class placed?

Comment: In this Package  -------
package com.sample.validation;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

Comment: @sandi You need to pass "com.sample.validation.Validation" as a parameter to the method.

Comment: Hi Its working...But I am facing this error  ------java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: 1940-02-10
 at java.lang.Class.getField(Unknown Source)
 at com.sample.validation.Validation.validateByType(Validation.java:30)
 at com.sample.validation.Validation.readJSON(Validation.java:20)
 at com.sample.validation.Validation.main(Validation.java:41)

Comment: Actullay this is the Json data I am getting as output ----{"birthday":"1940-02-10","favorite_foods":["cookie","chips","fish"],"passport":{"nationality":"American","id":100001},"car":null,"name":"Tom","married":false,"age":76}
76

Comment: @sandi  In this line  Field f = c.getField(jsonField); , you are trying to get a Field by reflection. To get a field by reflection, it must be a member variable of the class while in your case it's a local variable in the validateByType() method.

Comment: Can you slove this and Convert JSON values into their appropriate data types..I am  new for this coding ... So little bit confuesd

Comment: The getField() method also takes the simple name of the public field as a parameter. I recommend that you take some time to study reflection if you want to use it. A good place to start is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html